# Are complex analytic subsets of affine space necessarily zero sets of a globally defined holomorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let me fix some terminology.

Let's say $U \subset \mathbb{C}^m$ is said to be a complex analytic subset if it can be covered by open subsets $V_i$ such that $U\cap V_i$ is the zero set of holomorphic functions $f_1,...,f_n$ on $V_i$.

Is it true that if $U$ is closed, there is a single chart $V\subset \mathbb{C}^m$ with holomorphic functions $f_1,...,f_n$ on $V$ such that $U=\{z\in V:f_i(z)=0,\forall i\}$?

I guess there are two issues.

The first problem is that if you have $f_i$ on $V$ and $g_i$ on $V'$ that agree on the intersection is there a unique $V$ and $V'$ that is holomorphic on $V\cup V'$. I think basiaclly this is resolved by using analytic continuation for holomorphic functions in several variables by Hartog's theorem.

The second issue is something that is bothering me. If your $U$ is locally cut out by one holomorphic function, we can patch these together to get a holomorphic function on one chart. But say on $V_1$, it is the zero set of $f_1,...,f_n$ and on $V_2$, it is the zero set of $g_1,...,g_n$ how do I know that for each $f_i$ there is a $g_j$ where they agree on the intersection?

Comment: I think you should require that $U \subset \mathbb C^m$ is closed. Otherwise something like $\{(w,z) \in \mathbb C^2 : |w|, |z| < 1; wz=1\}$ is not cut out by global holomorphic functions.

Comment: @red_trumpet You're right. Let me edit this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is true for dimensional reason : the dimension of you analytic set $A$ is not constant. Indeed, take $A = \{0\} \cup \{z = 1\}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. $A$ is analytic with dimension $0$ at $\{0\}$ and dimension $1$ at each $(1,w)$. $A$ is defined by two equations in the neighborhood of $0$ ($z = w = 0$) but only one in the neihborhood of $\{z = 1\}$. For this reason, I don't think it can be globally defined by $1$ neither $2$ equations globally.

**Edit**

As you said, $A = V(w(z - 1),z(z - 1))$ and in fact an algebraic subset of $\mathbb{C}^m$ can not be a counter-example for the simple reason that $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_m]$ is Noetherian.

I couldn't find a counter-example in general and I even think your result is true for $m = 1$ and for closed analytic subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. Indeed, closed analytic subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are $\mathbb{C}$ itself and its discrete subsets. Let $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ be discrete. In particular, $A$ is countable so we can write $A = \{a_0,a_1,\ldots\}$. Assume up to translation that $0 \notin A$. You can maybe buid a holomorphic function of this kind,
$$
f(z) = \prod_{n \geqslant 0} \left(1 - \frac{z}{a_n}\right)\exp\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{\lambda_n} \frac{z}{ka_n^k}\right)
$$
This inspires from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem. The idea is to choose the $\lambda_n$ large enough to have uniform convergence and if $f$ is well defined, $A = f^{-1}\{0\}$. Maybe this method can be generalized to closed analytic subsets of $\mathbb{C}^m$ by considering an infinite decomosition in irreducible components and build a product like that (at least for hypersurfaces).

Your problem looks like the problem "Is the field of meromorphic funcitons on a complex connected manifold $X$ the field of fraction of its ring of holomorphic functions ?" where you try to transform local holomorphic into global holomorphic. For example, the answer of this problem is yes when $X$ is a polydisk of $\mathbb{C}^m$ (including $\mathbb{C}^m$ itself) but wrong in general (take $\mathbb{P}^m(\mathbb{C})$ for example). Your problem is obviously true in the $\mathbb{P}^m(\mathbb{C})$ because in those sets analytic $=$ algebraic, but I have no idea in general...

Comment: I don't think I buy what you said. Assuming $\{0\}$ means the set with one point $\{(0,0)\}$, isn't the $A$ that you described $V(w,z)\cup V(z-1)$? Then, using that $V(I)\cup V(J)=V(IJ)$, I think we have $A=V(w(z-1),z(z-1))$.

Comment: To me, a similar style of question would be "Is the closed subscheme of an affine scheme necessarily affine?". Or in other words, to see if I have a closed subscheme do I really have to pass to a local affine open  and check it there or can I do it globally?